# Error in my menu xml file

Tags: android

here is the code that is said to have error:

```
<menu     
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context="absolute.begginners.hellouniverse.MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
       app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

and the error message is:
error: No resource identifier found for attribute '`showAsAction`' in package '`packegie.com.myApp`'

Comment: what version of android are compiling against ?

Comment: Can you try remove app tool and context tags. And add <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> to start.

Answer (score 0):

ShowAsAction is available after API level 11.
 http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html